# How do I trigger builds by specific users and VCS roots on TeamCity?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

I tried filtering by user, where `domain\user` is the username as it appears in TFS. However, this resulted in no builds triggering at all.

```
+:user=domain\user1  
+:user=domain\user2
```

Then I tried this

```
+:.  
+:user=domain\user1  
+:user=domain\user2
```

This triggers builds, but on every checkin by every user, which is not my intention. Is there some known bug (which I didn't find) or am I doing something wrong? I used VS solution builder for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the rule you added to the top of your list is going to add all users `+:.`. I was able to add a build trigger filter for my TFS repository/configuration like this

```
+:user=omnyx\anthony.mastrean
```

I did not try using a VCS root filter, but I imagine it works [as specified in the documents](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-buildTriggerRules). Especially, because it worked so quickly (unlike [other TeamCity filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631533/how-do-i-exclude-types-and-methods-from-being-covered-by-dotcover-in-teamcity-6/6208644#6208644)).

If you've gotten the answer from the [TeamCity forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/293332;jsessionid=784345E4CF20105F169BFA240BC943BD), please cross-post it so we don't have to Google for it later.