# How can I exclude namespaces in code coverage with Team City?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, code-coverage, dotcover

I am using Team City 7.1.1 (build 24074), and I would like to exclude some **namespaces** in code coverage. 
I am using dotcover as code coverage tool.
I am using MSPec, Machine.Fakes and Rhino Mocks in my tests.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631533/how-do-i-exclude-types-and-methods-from-being-covered-by-dotcover-in-teamcity-6

Comment: But in this case exclude namespace means exclude all types from it. Did you try example from that question? `+:Omnyx.Scanner
-:Omnyx.Scanner;type=Omnyx.Scanner.Simulation.*`

Comment: Yes, I have tried It until I got success. I expected to have some filter like -:assemblyName;namespace=namespace but it doesn´t exists :(. THANKS

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally I have found the way to exlude **NAMESPACES**

-:*assemblyName*;type=*nameSpace*.*

Comment: In all of internet, this is the only answer that actually does it. Whoever's looking has to look here. Great job cdiazal

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help all the internet ;)

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks

Comment: @cdiazal but I think we don'r have argument by name :-assemblyName  only we have Module, class mask and function. And type= is the name of the namespace we want to exclude please correct me if I am wrong I am new to this.

Comment: @NetSurfer maybe this have changed in newer versions, sorry but now I am using Azure DevOps I can´t help you this time.